# Парсинг! Вывод результата n\a. Можно ли как-то исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
url = 'https://whoer.net/ru'
page = requests.get(url)

item= BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
new_list = item.find('div',{'id':'anonymizer'},{'class':'ip-data__col ip-data__col_value'}).text #анонимайзер
new_list1 = item.find('span',{'class':'cont proxy-status-message'}).text #прокси
new_list2 = item.find('span',{'class':'cont dns_br_ip underlined max_ip'}).text
print(new_list)
print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я выполнил этот код, и, как я понял, вас не устраивает то, что строка

```
print(new_list2)
```

выдает N/A?
В таком случае, могу сказать, что это "проблема" сайта, к которому вы обращаетесь, так как он действительно содержит

```
 <span class="cont dns_br_ip underlined max_ip"><span class="disabled">N/A</span></span>
```

Если же проблема в том, что надо вывести что-то вместо `N/A`, то можно сделать

```
if new_list2 == 'N/A':
    *нужные действия*
```

Comment: @slug ну смотрите, я выполнил код, который вы привели. Строчка, о которой мы говорим, судя по написанному, ищет содержимое span'a на сайте. На сайте, как я уже и сказал, лично у меня содержится `N/A`, так что ваш код работает верно, либо скажите, что конкретно вы ожидаете увидеть

Comment: нужно получить те данные которые сайт выдает, например: если я использую TOR програма должна выдать  - ДА(спарсить з сайта ответ, иначе - нет. А у меня постоянно N\A). Может вы знаете програмы для линукса на проверку ананимности IP напишите

Comment: @slug бюось, что вы это не по адресу попали :), потому что ваш код в итоге выдает верный ответ, а что уже выдает сайт - дело не вашего кода. За программами советую обратиться к гуглу